# Run app under admin account not allowed to create folder

Tags: c#, windows, uac

I have an app that cannot create or delete a folder in its installation directory which is c:\appName.

The app is run under an administrator account but has not being run with elevated permissions.

Is it the fact that it is not elevated that is the issue or that I am trying to create/delete a folder in the installation directory?

Comment: what is the app an exe?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is an exe (a wpf application)

Comment: The fact that its the installation directory is irrelevant, so presumably the permissions on the directory require elevation.

Comment: I just noticed that if I delete a folder as Directory.Delete(".\\abc", true) this does not work but Directory.Delete("c:\\data\\abc", true) works. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to force your WPF application to run in **Administrator mode**.

This can be done by adding an **app.manifest** to the project and changing **requestExecutionLevel** from **asInvoker** to **requireAdministrator**. This will cause the UAC prompt to show when your application is run, and elevate the permissions of your application to a level where it can create/delete as needed.

MSDN has complete instructions on how to achieve this, which can be accessed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).